# Analog input buffer for an A/D Converter - what op-amp to use?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, adc

For a small audio-recorder project i'm currently working on i will use a Nanopi Neo and an audio chip from Cirrus Logic. I'm pretty stable in my skills as soon as it comes to the digital side of the project, but the analog circuitery somehow bothers me.

For the analog input buffers of the A/D converter an example circuit is being provided. It looks like this:

[image]

What Op-Amps should i use for this? Is there any special requirements to them?

---

edit, additional information:

Offset Voltage should be at 2.5V, with +-1.4V when arriving at the pins of the chip. I'm not quite sure what the input voltage to the circuit is going to be, as the requirement for -10 dBV or +4 dBu are not yet clear. THD should not be an issue, it's just an experiment right now, i would be glad not to have excessive noise though. What would that mean for the choice to make?

Comment: "*Is there any special requirements to them?*" Yes.... and they make this question unanswerable as is. You need to know frequency requirements, signal levels, power supplies available, what kind of offset error you can accept as a minimum.

Comment: Usually they make a reccomendation or you can't find an app note or dev board if you don't know how to size op amps on your own

Comment: Are you seeking 20 or 24 bit performance? At what sample rate? Is that ADC delta-sigma with 10MegaSamples/second?

Comment: 24 bit, the sample range is going to be in the usual audio sampling range, which is between 44.1 kHz and 192 kHz.

Comment: Oh, and it is delta-sigma with "digital filtering and no need for analog antialiasing" - i should have provided this right from the start, but the chips in question are https://www.cirrus.com/products/cs5351/ and https://www.cirrus.com/products/cs5361/

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The opamps are configured as pretty basic unity gain buffers with an output low pass filter feeding into the ADC stage. This means they don't need much gain-bandwidth capability, much output current capacity, and even the input impedance requirements are not that important. As the system is working with audio, the input offset voltage isn't that important either.

The main requirement you need to watch will be the input and output voltage range with respect to what the ADC expects and the power supply you have available. Any low voltage rail-to-rail opamp should be more than adequate in this regard.

Given that this is an audio system, I'd say the most important characteristic will be the noise and distortion performance. Opamps operating as buffers have very low THD anyway, but some people believe you can hear even tiny amounts. Noise, however, will be something that is quite apparent if you choose a bad opamp, and I would probably focus on minimizing this as a priority.

Comment: They also need to be stable under relatively large (2.7 nF) capaciitive loads

Comment: Not really, they need to be stable under 2.7n + 91 ohms, which is a much less harsh constraint.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the function of the opamps, didn't think of them being unity gain buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Providing I had suitable power rails available I would be reaching for a couple of NE5532 (Jellybean audio opamp) or OPA2134 (Not really better, but some people are down on the 5532 for no reason I understand).

You will need to watch the ABS MAX voltage for the AIN pins, particularly during any start up transients, a set of clamp diodes is a good plan.

I would note that that input stage imposes any common mode noise onto the input of the ADC, which may limit performance in the presence of significant noise or a single ended source, there are better circuits.

The opamp choice becomes much harder if you only have say +-5V available, ideally you want at least +-12V or so if you want to use the usual opamps.

Comment: As described the A/D converter will be part of a NanoPi setup (similar to Raspberry Pi), a +-5V power source will be available. I would like to avoid the need for an additional +-12V power source